# Скрипт PHP не загружает файл с формы

Tags: php, apache2

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, пишу свой мини-блог, пытаюсь отправить файл через форму, и вроде все хорошо, я вывожу $_FILES, он как бы загружается, пишет даже путь, куда этот файл загрузился, но, зайдя в эту папку(/tmp/) этого файла попросту нет! Подскажите пожалуйста, куда сохраняются временные файлы? У меня Ubuntu/Apache2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он должен там быть? Довольно логично ожидать, что после завершения обработки запроса весь временный хлам будет удаляться

Comment: Тоесть могу дальше прописывать скрипт на перемещение файла?

Comment: То есть можешь. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Как только скрипт отработал, файл удаляется. Нужно переместить этот временный файл, во время исполнения скрипта (до его завершения)